# Same URL showing different content (website is mine)

Tags: url, http-status-code-403

OK, this is weird.

We have a test website (just a payment form) here: http://blog.inglesen100dias.com/

The problem is that everyone I've talked to but me can see the form (our hosting provider, other coworkers in different states/countries, etc). Me, I see a 403 forbidden error, "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

We made a change earlier today in that subdomain, changing the A record to point it to a different server. But for some reason everyone but me can see the new page where it's pointing at.

I've deleted the cache, flushed the DNS (I'm on Windows 8), entered the website with my cellphone (same error)... so I don't know what else to do. My impresion is that when I access that URL, it's still trying to open a location in the old server (where the domain originally pointed), instead of in the new server. Why this only happens to me?

Any advice would be very welcome!

**UPDATE**

I've turned-off the Wifi in my cellphone (it's connected to the same network as my computer) and now it shows the right page! If I turn the wifi back on, then it shows the 403 error again...
Can it be a problem in the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the router and now it's showing the right page!